# How to get index for parent loop in Handlebars template?

Tags: handlebars.js

```
<script id="contact-row" type="text/x-handlebars-template" >

    {{#each rows}}
      <tr>
           {{getInputField @index "country" country }}

          {{#each contactData}}
            {{getInputFieldForData @index "contractName" contractName }}
          {{/each}}
      </tr>
    {{/each}}
```

I want to get the index of the parent in the inner #each loop. I tried ../@index but that gives error.

Comment: What is the error it gives? Are you iterating over a collection of objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this is not currently possible the way you want to do it: https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/issues/491

But you could set the index to a new variable in the outer scope to access it.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like things have changed...

To get the index of a parent `{{#each}}` block from within a child `{{#each}}` block use the `{{@../index}}` syntax.

```
{{#each foo}}
    {{@index}}           // Parent Index Reference
    {{someProperty}}     // Parent property
    {{#each baz}}
        {{@index}}       // Child Index Reference
        {{@../index}}    // Parent Index Reference <--
        {{someProperty}} // Child property
    {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

The link in the accepted answer has this solution, just posting the details here for posterity's sake.